# Only child class overrides interface methods in Java

Tags: java, interface

I know that each class that implements some `Interface` must override all its methods. Except if current class is `abstract`.

As you can see under mentioned template of code demonstrates that.

IN my case only `ChildClass` overrides `foo()` method.

**Interface**

```
public interface MyItf {
   public void foo();
}
```

**Parent class**

```
public abstract class ParentClass implements MyItf {

}
```

**Child class**

```
public class ChildClass extends ParentClass{

  @Override
  public void foo() {

  }
}
```

But this implementation demands me to set `ParentClass` class to be `abstract`.

What if I want to leave `ParentClass` to be single class and not abstract?

Does anyone have other ways where only *children* use `MyItf` but not Parent class?

Thank you,

**[EDIT]**

Based on all answers I found solution in my case:

I code a game where I have 140 child classes.

To make code more flexible I need create "empty" interface and allow to all children to implement it, like:

```
 public interface UnknownItf {

 }
```

So next time If I need to add new interface to children I'll just write:

```
public interface UnknownItf extends NewItf{
   ///...
}
```

Comment: If `ParentClass` doesn't implement all interface methods, it cannot be instantiated.  Therefore it must be `abstract`.

Comment: Maybe you should override `Foo` in your `ParentClass`, too.

Comment: You've answered your own question in your first two sentences. What exactly is it that you're confused about?

Comment: in my game I have 140 children and instead to add interface to each child thought to add interface to parent "Base" class. But it forces me to make it abstract

Comment: Yes, as you said yourself in your first two sentences. That's the rule. You stated it correctly. What's the question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What if I want to leave ParentClass to be single class and not abstract?

Well you can't - you've declared that it implements the interface, but you've provided no implementation.

In other words, what would you expect this code to do?

```
MyItf itf = new ParentClass();
itf.foo();
```

If `ParentClass` were concrete, that would have to compile... but you've provided no implementation for `foo`.

If you only want the subclasses to implement `MyItf`, then simply don't declare that the superclass implements it. If you're trying to force *all* subclasses to implement it, but not the superclass, and you don't want the superclass to be abstract, then I'm afraid there's no way of doing that - and it would be a questionable design even if it were possible. (How would it be useful?)

Comment: In my case I use `MyItf itf = new ChildClass();` but most logic stays into `ParentClass`

Comment: I have 140 child classes and thought just to add Interface to Parent class and do not run over all classes. So seems no way just add interface to children only. thanks

Comment: @MaximShoustin: Any time you've got 140 subclasses, that sounds odd to start with - *particularly* if you want the superclass to be a concrete class. If all 140 subclasses implement the same interface but you never need the superclass to implement the interface, that sounds odd too. Basically I think you should step back and revisit your whole design, rather than just concentrating on the aspect of wanting to add an interface just to subclasses.

Comment: in game child class represents Unit on  the screen. all logic stays in Parent class but for flexibility I use only interfaces to deal with

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone have other ways where only children use MyItf but not Parent class?

Don't make the parent class implement the interface and have the child class implement the interface.

The language doesn't rightly allow you to do both (declare parent class as interface type and then skip implementing methods, if you wish to skip implementing methods it's incomplete and hence should be abstract)

Comment: yes, I know, I have 140 child classes and thought just to add Interface to Parent class

Answer (score 1):

If a class implements an interface the class, or its super-classes MUST implement the interface methods OR be abstract.
Both at the same time is possible too. then, the children wouldn't need to implement the methods.

If you only want children to implement an interfece write it to the child-classes and not the super-class

Answer (score 0):

The reason of why you can not do it is simple:

The compiler find that the `ParentClass` implements the `MyItf` interface then tries to find the implementation of `foo` method. 
The below:

```
public class ParentClass implements MyItf
```

Means:
Java compiler **ParentClass** will implement all methods defined in **MyItf**

So there is no way you can tell the compiler that:

"JAVAC don't worry!! The `ParentClass` **will** have some `ChildClass`that  **will** implement the `foo` method. So just go on..."